# How to monitor link with java watchservice

Tags: java, linux, watchservice

How to monitor a file updated (file is actual.txt below)? But I just want to monitor the link folder.

ln -s ../actual.txt link

```
    Path path = Paths.get(".");

    WatchService watchService =  path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
    path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
    WatchKey watchKey = null;
    while (true) {
        watchKey = watchService.poll(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        if(watchKey != null) {
            watchKey.pollEvents().stream().forEach(event -> System.out.println(event.context()));
        }
        watchKey.reset();
    }
```

But this code is not work.

Comment: Update file actual.txt , but monitor folder where link exists

Comment: If monitor the directory of actual.txt , is ok , but I just want to monitor link file. How to do ?